# Uploading gpg key to Launchpad

Tags: gnupg, launchpad, keyserver

I am trying to upload my GPG key's 'fingerprint' as per the instructions on Launchpad. I have a valid key pair, I uploaded to the Ubuntu Keyserver, then after I could see the key on the KeyServer, I pasted the fingerprint into the Launchpad page.  Checked the page said it would send a email to me at the correct address. Pressed the "Import key" button.

No email.

12 Hours later, I wondered if I was too quick (even though I did wait until I could see it on the KeyServer) so repeated the process. An hour ago. **Just to be clear, I am not getting an email back from Launchpad when I submit my key's fingerprint.**

(as a test I updated my incredibly old Launchpad dsa key to a current rsa one, received an immediate email.)

Am I expecting too fast a response or should I expect an error message if something goes wrong ?

Davo

Comment: I got the email encrypted with my key in seconds, as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with the help of the Launchpad people. The issue is that the Launchpad screen where you enter the key's fingerprint times out. But does not indicate it has done so.   When I entered the fingerprint and pressed Import, it took me to a re-login screen.  I thought it was processing my input but in fact had discarded the input as the session had expired.

By ensuring you are ready to proceed, not flicking through various documentation tabs, when you get to the fingerprint page, it all works as expected.

Davo